# Como chamar Projetos adicionados como referência em C#

Tags: c#

Tenho vários projetos e quero fazer um form com botões e chama-los. Pesquisando vi que posso fazer isso adicionando um outro projeto como referência, até aí tudo bem, mais como fazer depois que adicionar o projeto como referência? Como chama-lo através de um botão?

Comment: Defina melhor como é esse "chamar um projeto". O que são esses projetos? Executáveis? Projetos Web? DLL's?

Comment: São um UDP com client e server, ambas as telas são projetos diferentes em Console. Com  telas WindowsForm eu tenho uma RPC e um TCP, que ambas também são projetos diferentes. Nenhum destes projetos são web, são executáveis.

Comment: Meio confuso. Você quer se comunicar entre aplicativos?

Comment: Não quero comunicação, quero que em uma tela esteja referenciado(tela principal com botões) todos os projetos e eu possa chamar cada um independente, tudo isso através de um botão para cada projeto.

Comment: ... você diz uma tela para executar outras aplicações? não consegui entender o que você está querendo fazer. Elabore mais a sua pergunta, apresentando um [MCVE]